# Dispatcher whitelisting for doFilter servlet in AEM

Tags: caching, filter, aem, servlet-filters, dispatcher

I have got a filter servlet in AEM which is used for custom authentication & and redirect handling on the websites.

Currently, all the user-specific pages are getting served from the publish instance in AEM and caching is not enabled on these pages. Hence my forced-login scenario works.

If I want to use the dispatcher to serve these pages, Filter Servlets are not triggered and the user is able to access these pages even if logged out with broken/missing details. Can we add any configuration in the dispatcher to allow filter servlets even on dispatcher-cached pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Dispatcher while having AEM maintain control over which users see which resources, the most natural way to do this is through configuring the `auth_checker` in your Dispatcher config. It mostly boils down to defining glob patterns to instruct it which requests require an auth check and which ones do not and pointing at a servlet that handles the authorization.

The official documentation contains [decent guidelines on the topic](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/permissions-cache.html?lang=en)